# error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'const int')|

Tags: c++, pointers

I was just learning macros and working of pointers/references through a simple program of calculating area.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define PI = 3.141592653589793238
#define AREA(new_r) (PI*new_r*new_r)
#define PERIMETER(new_r) (2*PI*new_r)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the radius:";
    int r = 0;
    cin >> r;
    int *new_r = &r;
    printf("\n%darea",AREA(new_r),"\n%dPerimeter:", PERIMETER(new_r));
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving out this error;

```
C:\Users\aakash\Desktop\C++\Eight_C++\main.cpp|11|error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'const int')|
```

I'm a beginner so please explain if I'm lacking any basic/crucial knowledge here.

Comment: A few warnings. `#define AREA(r) (PI*new_r*new_r)` doesn't use `r`. `new_r` is a pointer, so `PI*new_r*new_r` isn't going to be multiplying. `printf` doesn't use the insertion operator (`<<`).

Comment: There are at least 5 error in this code. Having `const` in the declaration of `r` is the least of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the code.

> `#define PI = 3.141592653589793238`

The proper format to declare macro is: `#define <macroName> <macroValue>`. There is no need to use `=` sign. And so the proper way should be `#define PI 3.141592653589793238`.

> ```
> #define AREA(r) (PI*new_r*new_r)
> #define PERIMETER(r) (2*PI*new_r)
> ```

It is logical to use `r` in the formula instead of `new_r`. Also, `new_r` is a pointer and so it will not give the expected output.

> ```
> const int r = 0;
>     cin >> r;
> ```

**This is the reason behind the error message!** We use `const` during declaration of a variable to define that the assigned value of the variable should not be changed under any circumstances. By `const int r = 0;` we mean that the value of `r` should always be 0 and can not be changed. And that's why we can't input a value in `r`. So to store a value, we need to use another variable that is not `const`.

> ```
> printf("\n%darea:"<<" "<<AREA(new_r)<<"\n%dPerimeter:"<< PERIMETER(new_r));
> ```

`cout` and `printf()` are two different things. `printf()` use **format specifiers** and not **`<<`** to output values. Correct way to use `printf()` in this case:

```
printf("\narea: %f\nPerimeter: %f", AREA((*new_r)), PERIMETER((*new_r)));
```

So, the final code should look something like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#define PI 3.141592653589793238
#define AREA(r) (PI*r*r)
#define PERIMETER(r) (2*PI*r)

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the radius:";
    int r = 0;
    cin >> r;
    int *new_r = &r;

    printf("\narea: %f\nPerimeter: %f", AREA((*new_r)), PERIMETER((*new_r)));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const int r = 0;`

You are initializing a constant value, you can't reassign it as you've done

`cin >> r;`

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer!But even after removing the "const" from both "r" and and "new_r" declarations,i'm getting the following error:main.cpp|13|error: invalid operands of types 'const char [9]' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator<<'|

Comment: @Dindayal the code you have presented contains a lot of mistakes. picking off the errors one by one is going to loop pretty grim for a while because you're not going to see much change. If you can, replace the macros with functions. Functions are orders of magnitude smarter than macros, glorified cut-and-paste replacements, and can catch a lot of trivial mistakes with much easier-to-understand error messages.